# Why won't Visual Studio load symbols when attaching to a container's w3wp process?

Tags: docker, container

I want to debug my code running in a Sitecore CM Docker container. When I attach my debugger, it never breaks at my breakpoints and hovering over them always says

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

Why won't it attach properly?

### How I attach to process

1. Open the **Containers** window (**View** menu -> **Other Windows** -> **Containers**)
2. Right-click on my CM container and click **Attach to Process**

   [image: Containers window with attach to process menu item]
3. Select **w3wp.exe** and click **Attach**

   [image: Attach to process window]
4. Mouse over my breakpoint and see "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

### What else I've tried

1. Ensuring I have the **DEBUG** constant defined and **Full** debugging information enabled on my project for my build configuration
2. Rebuilding the solution
3. Verifying that the ***.pdb** files have been deployed to the container's `bin` directory

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set the code type to **Managed (.NET 4.x) code** in the **Attach to:** section of the **Attach to Process** dialog in order for debugging to work. **Automatic** does not load symbols.

[image: Attach to process dialog with Managed (.NET 4.x) code type selected]

Comment: I've been stuck for two hours on this. I just started using VS 2022 and this was the solution. Thank you, thank you, thank you.